# What's the difference between a mitogen and a cell cycle stimulant substance?

Tags: cell-biology, cell-signaling, mitosis, cell-cycle

It's been a week since I got this question asked and I still have no clue. I have thought that the main difference would be that the mitogen induces mitosis, and the cell cycle stimulant substance accelerates the cell cycle. I don't really know, to be honest.

Comment: What do you mean "got this question asked"? Was it part of an assignment for a course? In that case I'd look at the course materials or ask your instructor. If not, why do you need this answer? Where are you seeing these terms used and where are those usages in conflict? We expect questions to include some background information necessary to identify the specific question asked and the level of understanding it is asked with. "Cell cycle stimulant" is not something I find many hits for on e.g. Google Scholar, is this a translation?

Comment: Yes, it is part of an assignment, we don't really have course material, and the question was asked precisely by my instructor. The use of these terms is in the cell cycle topic. I am sorry that I did not give enough context to answer my question. The concrete question was "What is the difference between a mitogenic substance and a cell cycle stimulating substance?"

Comment: You have an instructor and a course and no materials? That doesn't really seem to set you up for success. I'd ask your instructor what they mean by this. It doesn't seem to be a phrase other people use.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that too while searching about those terms. I'm gonna ask him tomorrow about this, because it's really confusing. I really appreciate you for taking part of your time to answer my question.

Comment: Sounds good, curious to hear what you find.